# PowerShell - Rest API GET call on 2.0

Tags: api, powershell

I need to do an API Get call on PowerShell 2.0 so I can't use the `Invoke-RestMethod` as it was introduced in version 3.0.

Anyone know how it can be done using PowerShell 2.0?

I have the following so far but don't know how to get the data from it. Preferably to a text file.

```
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('http://www.google.com')
```

How do I extract data from it?
If pasted into a browser it returns a simple text file with data in it.

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of [How to POST .json file in Powershell without Invoke-WebRequest?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24436478/608772).  I give the a function to call .NET classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is calling into the .NET Framework, so you could convert the code samples on the [MSDN documentation to PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc(v=vs.110).aspx).

**However**, when using PowerShell 2.0 I find it easier to use the [`DownloadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of `WebClient`:

```
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$data = $client.DownloadString('https://api.mysite.com/resource')
Set-Content -Value $data -Path 'resource.txt'
```

If the output is an XML document you can simply cast the returned string to `XML`:

```
$xmlData = [xml]$data
```

If the output is JSON then you can use the functions from [PowerShell 2.0 ConvertFrom-Json and ConvertTo-Json implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077854/powershell-2-0-convertfrom-json-and-convertto-json-implementation).

Comment: Hi Richard, Great help. I am able to get the data out.  I cannot convert the data into xml - i get the following error - "There are multiple root elements. Line 2, position 2."

Comment: That's probably because the API you are calling is adding in some extra data, perhaps post an example as a new question, be sure to [run a search first though](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=There+are+multiple+root+elements.+Line+2%2C+position+2).

Comment: Hi Richard, a valid point has been made to me and need to make an amendment. The API for the host maybe down or not exist. Therefore how would I add logic to test the API call first. Any ideas for powershell 2.0? Thanks

Comment: I did Richard, resolved using Try catch method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37279103/test-webclient-api-call